# postinst script in hand-rolled .deb reported not found

Tags: debian, dpkg

I had a quick dpkg/debian-izing question. I am trying to create a `.deb`(by hand - mostly for learning purposes) and I have rolled up an `ar`-chive with the `control.tar.gz`, `data.tar.gz` and the `debian-binary` files.

This hand-rolled `.deb` works fine for regular installs, purges et al. However when I specify an `--instdir` at install time, `dpkg` reports a 'file not found' error when trying to run the `postinst` script. This is not an issue with the `prerm` script, btw(which works fine).

Running `dpkg` with `--debug=2000` and looking at `/var/log/dpkg.log` didn't help much.

Any thoughts on why this could be happening?

TIA.

---

To give some more context and pose another question: I am trying to get `--instdir` to work mostly because the top level directory to which my package contents get installed is also a mount point and on doing `dpkg -P foo`, `dpkg` attempts to remove this directory. If anyone can suggest a workaround for this, that would serve my purpose too(i.e. I wouldn't need `--instdir` to work). Also, this top-level directory is not empty, so not sure why `dpkg` is attempting to [remove it](http://pastebin.com/ZiGtWz0m). Putting a `.placeholder` file in there didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

As it is listed here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921626/run-time-installation-directory-of-debian-package-contents) dynamic directory paths are not supported in deb packages with prepackaged binaries. But you can specify the directory path not at runtime but in your control file. And for easy making of packages you can use some graphical tools (ex., mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8055/graphical-tool-for-creating-deb-packages).